# Is $ \{x\in E | f(x) \le g(x)\}$ measurable if f and g are measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to show that the set 
$$X = \{x\in E | f(x) \le g(x)\}$$ 
is measurable. Here $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions over a measurable set $E$.

My solution is, 
$$X = \cup_{q \in Q} \{\ \{x |  f(x) \le q\} \cap \{x| g(x) \ge q\}\}$$ 
is measurable, because RHS is countable union of measurable sets which should be measurable.

> But aren't we ignoring the cases where $f(x)\le a$ and $g(x)\ge a$, where $a$ is irrational.

Comment: Have you shown that the sum of measurable functions is measurable?

Comment: In fact i wanted to use this to show that sum of measurable function is measurable. In that proof also something along this lines are used. And the same problem I am having in it too.

Comment: Show that the set $E=\{\,x : f(x)>g(x)\,\}$ is measurable (Per an adaptation your argument. Your objection will disappear now.). Then your result will follow upon considering $E^C$ and interchanging the roles of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: But how do i get rid of uncounatble -> :X  number of irrationals.

Comment: You don't have to worry about that. $f(x)>g(x)$ if and only if there is a rational number $\alpha$ with $f(x)>\alpha>g(x)$. So for $E$ as in my comment above $$E=\bigcup_{q\in\Bbb Q}\bigl(\,  \{\,x\mid f(x)>q\,\}\cap     \{\,x\mid g(x)<q\,\}\,\bigr) . $$

Comment: oh, god finally. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you are ignoring the case where $f(x)=g(x)=a$ for irrational $a$; and in fact, your equality need not hold.

However,   consider the complement of your given set: 
$$X^c=\{\, x \in E\mid g(x)<f(x)\,\}.$$

Your approach will work here: since $g(x)<f(x)$ if and only  and only if there is a rational number $a$ with $g(x)<a<f(x)$, you can write
$$
X^c=\bigcup_{q\in \Bbb Q}\bigr(\, \{\, x \in E \mid g(x)<q\,\} \cap  \{\, x \in E \mid f(x)>q\,\} \,\bigl).
$$
It follows that $X^c$ is measurable; thus, $X=\{\, x \in E \mid f(x)\le g(x)\,\}$ is measurable.

Comment: $E$ was used in the question, so I replaced $E$ with $X^c$

Comment: @David Mitra   If I want to prove that {x\in X : f(x)< g(x)} is measurable where $f ,g : X\to R$ are measurable, is it the same method?