# Prove $A=\{x\in X:f(x)=g(x)\}\in\mathcal F$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $R_0=[-\infty,\infty]$ and $(X,\mathcal F)$ be a measurable space.
>   If $f,g:X\to R_0$ is $\mathcal F-B(R_0)-$measurable functions then prove that $A=\{x\in X:f(x)=g(x)\}\in\mathcal F$.

Comment: First show that the set $\{ x \mid f(x)>g(x)\}$ is measurable (see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310320/is-the-set-x-in-e-fx-le-gx-measurable-if-f-and-g-are-measurable/310388) ). Then the set $\{ x \mid f(x)\ge g(x)\}$ is measurable, since it's the complement of a set of the first type mentioned. Now note that the set  $\{ x \mid f(x)= g(x)\}$ is an intersection of two sets of the second type mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ and $g$ are measurable, then $\{x\in R_0 : f(x)>a\}$ and $\{x\in R_0 : g(x)<b\}$ are $\mathcal F$-measurable, $\forall a,b\in \mathbb R_0$. Note that: 
$$\{x\in R_0 : f(x)>g(x)\}=\bigcup \limits_{q\in \mathbb Q}\left(\{x\in R_0:f(x)>q\}\cap\{x\in R_0:g(x)<q\}\right)$$
Since $\{x\in R_0:f(x)>q\},\{x\in R_0:g(x)<q\}\in \mathcal F$, we conclude that $\{x\in R_0 : f(x)>g(x)\}\in\mathcal F$ , because $\mathcal F $ is a $\sigma-$algebra.

In the same way, $\{x\in R_0 : f(x)<g(x)\}\in \mathcal F$, therefore : 
$$\{x\in R_0 : f(x)<g(x)\}\cup\{x\in R_0 : f(x)>g(x)\}\in \mathcal F$$
which implies: 
$$\{x\in R_0 : f(x)=g(x)\}=\left(\{x\in R_0 : f(x)<g(x)\}\cup\{x\in R_0 : f(x)>g(x)\}\right)^c\in \mathcal F$$
$$\Rightarrow A
\in \mathcal F$$