# Equal Measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to understand measure theory and I cannot figure out how to prove the following statement: if $g,h:[0,1]\rightarrow R$ are measurable functions, then the set {$x\in [0,1]:g(x)=h(x)$} is a measurable set. I now think that it may not be true. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: In some treatments (e.g., Hewitt and Stromberg), the fact that $g-h$ is measurable is proven after (and using) the fact that the set $\{\,x \mid f(x)>g(x)\,\}$ is measurable. Once this is proven, one easily sees that its complement,  $\{\,x \mid f(x)\le g(x)\,\}$,  is measurable. A set of your form is an intersection of   sets of the latter type, and is, thus, measurable.  A proof that $\{\,x \mid f(x)>g(x)\,\}$ is measurable can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310320/is-the-set-x-in-e-fx-le-gx-measurable-if-f-and-g-are-measurable/310388).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If $g$, $h$ are measurable, then $g - h$ is measurable too. Consider $(g - h)^{-1}(\{0\})$.

Comment: I see so proving g-h^-1({0}) is measurable implies that the entire set is measurable?

Comment: @user85402 Yes. That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

If $g,h$ are measurable then also $g-h$ is. Now can you argue that
$$
\{x\in [0,1]:g(x)=h(x)\}=\{x\in [0,1]:g(x)-h(x)=0\}=(g-h)^{-1}(\{0\})
$$
is measurable?

Comment: I see so proving g-h^-1({0}) is measurable implies that the entire set is measurable?

Comment: Proving that $g-h$ is measurable implies that $(g-h)^{-1}(A)$ is a measurable set for all Borel sets $A$. In particular when $A=\{0\}$  which is what we use.