# Prove $\{X>Y\} \in \mathcal{A}$ if $X,Y$ are random variables measurable w.r.p.t $\mathcal{A}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let two random variables $X,Y: \Omega \rightarrow R$ and measurable w.r.p.t $\mathcal{A}$

When I prove $\{X>Y\} \in \mathcal{A}$, in one of the step I wrote:

$$ \{X>Y\} = \bigcup_{k\in R}(\{X \geq k\} \cap \{Y < k\}) \tag1$$

However, the answer is slightly different as follow:
$$ \{X>Y\} = \bigcup_{q\in Q}(\{X > q\} \cap \{Y < q\}) \tag2$$

So I am wondering if my step (1) is wrong?

Comment: No, you're right. This is true because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This may help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310320/is-x-in-e-fx-le-gx-measurable-if-f-and-g-are-measurable

Comment: Key point: sigma algebras are closed under *countable* unions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you wrote is correct, but in order to prove the event $\{X > Y\}$ is measurable, exhibiting it as an uncountable union won't get us anywhere, since $\sigma$-algebras are not guaranteed to be closed under uncountable unions.

Hence why the solution uses $\mathbb Q$ instead of $\mathbb R$ to exhibit $\{X > Y\}$ as a countable union of measurable events.

Comment: Thanks! I just recalled it now!

Comment: just one more question: since Q and N has the same cardinality, it would be the same to use integer N right?

Comment: @TJT: The integers won't work because they aren't dense in the real numbers

Comment: I see! so we want $\bigcup_{q\in Q}(\{X > q\} \cap \{Y < q\})$ to be dense in real number so it can cover the real number while still be countable unions

Comment: @TJT, yes that's right. If $X(\omega) > Y(\omega)$, then by density of $\mathbb Q$, there must be a $q(\omega)\in\mathbb Q$ such that $X(\omega) > q(\omega) > Y(\omega)$.

Comment: and that's also why using $\geq$ or not is not crucial since Q is dense and it will be cover by the union operation with other sets?